# How can I access elements that are in iframe

Tags: html, css

I am working with html and css, in my project for me code is coming dynamically. that's why I am not able to post code so that's why I am attaching code Image for your reference.[image]

What I am trying to do is I am trying to apply display none for this div

```
<div class="jsx-674079454"></div>
```

I tried this logic but it's not working

```
#wrapper > iframe > #document > html > head > body > #__next > div > div > div {
  display: none !important;
}
```

So please help me to resolve this issue.
If you have any questions please let me know thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: You can only access the contentWindow of an iframe if it is from the same origin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow And you can only do it using JS. CSS on the parent page cannot style elements on the iframed page.